# Automatically Add Accents to Letters

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, diacritics

I have a few buttons that should make it simple to add accents to letters so that for instance `é` can be typed by pressing the `´` button and then entering an `e`.

Is there any easy way to add a certain accent to any letter, so that I don't have to create dozens of if statements for every letter that can have this accent? Is there maybe a link between the Unicode number of the letter and the letter with an accent?

Any suggestions would be appreciated, Fabian

Comment: I would expect international users to be well-served by their local IMEs. Is this really necessary?

Comment: The keyboard on the iPhone has this built in does it not?. The user just holds down the button and the accented characters appear for them to choose.

Comment: It's for a vocabulary learning app and you don't have the keyboard localized to the language. You could press and hold the keys, but I find that this takes up a lot of time if you are a speed typer. Specially on iPad, it interrupts the typing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a simple combination of unicode math that you can apply here, but you can make your procedure much more efficient by making a lookup dictionary.

make the key be the letter + a symbol for the accent, then store it in a dictionary in your class

```
[dict setObject:@"é" forKey:@"e+accent1"];
```

Then later, using the letter pressed by the user, and using your accent button to generate the second half, construct the key and look it up in the dictionary. This way, you avoid all of the if statements. Remember to construct your dictionary in `init` or elsewhere.